# C++ : Can't free all memory in struct

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I have some trouble with free memeory allocated by C++ struct in some specific situations.
Here is my code.

```
struct PixelPatch
{
    float* weight;
    float* texels0;
    float sq0;
};
int main()
{
    int num_texels = 30;
    PixelPatch* patches = new PixelPatch[4000000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
    {
        patches[i].weight = new float[num_texels];
        patches[i].texels0 = new float[num_texels];
        for(int j = 0; j < num_texels; j++)
        {
            patches[i].weight[j] = j;
            patches[i].texels0[j] = j;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
    {
        delete []patches[i].weight;
        delete []patches[i].texels0;
    }
    delete []patches;
    return 0;
}
```

I use `htop` to monitor the memory occupation.
If `num_texels` is greater than 30, all memory is freed correctly.
However, in the situation that `num_texels` is `<= 30`, the following code

```
 delete []patches[i].weight;
 delete []patches[i].texels0;
```

are not functional, and memory usage has not changed. On the other hand, `delete []patches` is not affected by `num_texels` and always works.

If I use the `Debug` compilation mode in CMake, the 'magic number' of `num_texels` changes to 32. Greater than 32, works fine; less than 32, fails.

My working environment is Ubuntu 20.04 + gcc9 + C++11.

Comment: Not sure what you're seeing, but Valgrind says there's no leak with num_texels = 30.

Comment: I add a breakpoint at `return 0` so that I can monitor the memory occupation at the end of the program. If `num_texels <= 30`, htop shows that 1.6% memory are consumed. If `num_texels > 30`, the memory usage is 0%, which means all memory is freed correctly.

Comment: @hytdt Can't see anything wrong with the code. IDK much about LInux but I guess your mistake is thinking that freeing memory will return that memory to the O/S. C++ makes no such guarantee. C++ only guarantees that freed memory will be available for use by the program, not the O/S.

Comment: I believe htop is an external utility that does not necessarily have access to the C++ allocation library internals. As such, I expect that it is not suitable as a definitive check on memory memory leaks. I assume (but admittedly don't know)that it is susceptible to false negatives & positives. Instrument your code with a tool that is designed for the purpose of checking for memory leaks. As an example, in the past, library allocators sometimes kept some allocations to suballocate rather than return them to to OS. Would not be a leak, but would look like one from htop.

Comment: C++? Ever heard of std::vector and/or std:make_unique? Those will help you reduce memory allocation issues before they even start. In "modern" C++, the use of manual new/delete is no longer recommended

Comment: Could be other possibilities as well. I know of some, but I don't see that the ones I know of are applicable to your posted code. In any case, use the correct tool for the job. I don't think htop is it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, probably it is the problem of htop instead of my code. Using std::vector may slow down the speed since I have billion times of operation on the array.

Comment: If vector doesn't work for you, you might still consider using unique_ptr.

Comment: The C++ memory manager doesn't necessarily return memory to the OS when you free it, since you're very likely to want to allocate memory again and turning to the OS for memory is costly.

Comment: Your program releases memory, in the sense that your program can no longer use it (without introducing undefined behaviour).    That does not mean your program will release memory to the host system.   In fact, a common optimisation in the standard library (e.g. implementation of `operator new()` and `operator delete()` and related functions that allocate/release raw memory) is that memory released by your program is often NOT returned to the operating system, and instead is used to make subsequent allocations by your program faster.

Comment: Maybe the larger allocations need their own page(s) of memory. If so, freeing those allocations might be simpler to just return the whole page to the OS. In the end, wether or not the allocation is returned to the OS is an implementation detail. `delete` can keep the memory around to be reused by a future `new`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allocating in any special form (eg aligned to page size), I would strongly recommend you to rewrite your code using std::vector, as follows:

```cpp
#include <vector>
struct PixelPatch
{
    std::vector<float> weight;
    std::vector<float> texels0;
    float sq0;
};
int main()
{
    int num_texels = 30;
    std::vector<PixelPatch> patches(4000000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
    {
        patches[i].weight.resize( num_texels );
        patches[i].texels0.resize( num_texels );
        for(int j = 0; j < num_texels; j++)
        {
            patches[i].weight[j] = j;
            patches[i].texels0[j] = j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is way cleaner and much less error-prone.